# How can I remove unused packages from virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

How can I keep track of the packages when I install them using pip inside a virtualenv?

It seems like a mess now; if I install package A, it automatically install its dependancies; B, C and D. Then I decide to use package N instead which installs its dependancies as well.

Now when I remove package A, its dependancies are not automatically removed.

How I can keep my virtualenv clean? Is there a tool to check for unused packages and remove them?

Comment: "Now when I remove package A, its dependancies are not automatically removed" Thank god they are *not* removed! Dependencies can be used by any number of packages hence it is simply *incorrect* to remove them without a throughout check.

Comment: There are `pipenv` and `pip-autoremove`, although I'm not sure if it works in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Making virtualenvs is relatively cheap. You could just create a new virtualenv whenever you get into this situation and run your pip install again.

Not very elegant, but it gets the job done. Of course you need to be maintaining some requirements file for the pip install and it will go faster if you have some local index or cache for pip.

Comment: As long as there's no tool for cleaning dependencies, this seems the way to go.

Answer (score 20):

To remove a package:

```
pip uninstall package_name
```

To get list of packages required by any given package (using pip):

```
pip show package_name
```

This will show you the packages that are required for it to run, and also the packages that require your package for them to run.

So the best way to uninstall a package with all its dependency packages is to run `pip show package_name` first to see the list of its dependency packages and then uninstall it along with its dependency packages one by one. For example:

```
pip show package_name
pip uninstall package_name
pip uninstall dependency_package_1
pip uninstall dependency_package_2
```

...etc

Answer (score 7):

To get a clean environment, create a new one. Some pip hooks can help you on this path:

- `pip freeze` to get list of installed packages and their versions, wich can later be used with
- `-r <file>` to install list of packages, stated in a requirements file
- `--build <dir>` to place builds in a specific directory
- `--no-clean` to not clean up build directories
- later you can use those builds with `--no-download`
- `--no-deps` to not install dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way is to name each dependency of your project in your "setup.py" or "requirements.txt". Exercise setup.py or pip install `cat requirements.txt` multiple times with virtualenv in order to run your application successfully. After that, manually add the new dependency to one of the files to keep your dependency in sync.

Answer (score 0):

While the other responses are essentially correct, here are the specific steps I would recommend to accomplish what they suggest using Virtual Environments (note Conda is different, this only applies to the Virtual Environments you asked about):

First, ensure your requirements.txt file contains ONLY the packages which you have explicitly installed, along with required versions. You can generate the list through "pip freeze", but that command will list ALL packages, not just your "top level" ones, so be sure to prune it. The requirements.txt will look something like:

```
python-dotenv~=1.0.0
pypdf2~=3.0.1
...and so on...
```

Second, rename your existing venv directory by appending a -backup (so just in case anything goes awry, you can always get it back)

```
cd <project dir>
mv venv venv-backup
```

Go back in PyCharm, into Settings...->Project: MyProject->Python Interpreter. The "Python Interpreter" at the top will now be red, because it no longer sees your venv. Click "Add Interpreter"->"Add Local Interpreter...", and in the dialog that comes up, select Virtualenv Environment. Leave it at "New" and the location should be auto-filled with your old information. Click "OK".

Now go to the Terminal tab in PyCharm, and type:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That should reinstall into your new venv the latest version of everything that is compatible with the versions you've specified for your "top level" packages. It will also helpfully list which line of the requirements.txt file caused each additional package to get installed.

If everything looks good, you can delete venv-backup. (An alternative to the name change is to just create a second venv within PyCharm, switch to it, then delete the first when the new one works. I just don't like the constantly rotating venv names with that method.)

I agree that PyCharm should keep track of this better automatically, but until then, I hope this helps.